# The newline characters '/n' is getting printed instead of splitting to a newline

Tags: c#, console-application

To clarify, I understand I could use:

```
Console.WriteLine("sample text")
```

to get the desired effect, nevertheless, the code I'm using should work, and I want to know why it isn't.

The code sample:

```
Console.Write("You have chosen {0}, the game will now begin.{1} Newline.", x_or_o, "/n");
```

And the output I am receiving in the console is:

```
You have chosen x, the game will now begin./n Newline.
```

Whereas my desired output is:

```
You have chosen x, the game will now begin.
Newline.
```

Sorry if I'm missing something fundamental or obvious, but my SO and google searches have resulted in no solutions.

All answers are appreciated in advance, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The newline formatter is `\n` not `/n`

Comment: There is also the Environment.NewLine constant

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is the solution.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please mark the correct solution as the accepted answer if it helped you

Comment: Done. The reason I didn't do it earlier is because there is a cooldown time after posting before you can choose an answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's because newline character is `\n` not `/n`. Also, please use `Environment.NewLine` for the full Windows line break.

`\n` is just a line break, but for Windows `\r\n` is used as a newline sequence. That's what's in `Environment.NewLine`. Use that to make sure things work alright on other platforms, too, when running Mono for example.

Comment: Do you care to explain why? Seems kinda irresponsible just to state things  without explanation.

Comment: Which part do you need an explanation for? I can't explain why Microsoft chose `\r\n`, but using a constant defined by the runtime is a good idea, as other OSs do *not* use `\r\n` as the newline sequence. Linux for example uses `\n`, the Mac uses `\r`. Using the runtime-defined constant makes sure that you don't need to care for that stuff. So if you run on Mono on Linux or the Mac this will ensure your application works. Just like using drive letters or the `\` path separator is not a good idea if you want to be platform independent - use `Path.Combine` instead.

Comment: You edited your answer, thus giving it more clarification. Thanks.